# Authentication SSO token security - SAML, OpenID Connect

Tags: authentication, sso, token, saml, openid-connect

I am trying to understand how works various SSO technologies like SAML 2.0, OpenID Connect 1.0.

In general, they work in a similar way providing tokens (XML, JSON) through Identity Provider to Service Provider.

What I don't fully understand is how are these tokens secured so nobody can steal it and use it from different device in order to get authenticated session and impersonate.

Also, how are these tokens stored? Are they stored as a cookie in a browser? If so, would it be possible to steal a token cookie and use it to impersonate somebody?

How can I detect that the token is used in an unauthorised manner?

I am looking for a practical view how are tokens secured and represented when authentication is established or when using as SSO, so authentication is not required by Identity Provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tokens are secured at multiple level

1. Transport - Most of the specs recommend SSL (and some mandate it)
2. Use once - These token are just meant to transfer identity once and then the asserted identity can be attached with local session for further processing. Most of the specs contain safeguards to allow IdP & SP to track the generation and use of token only once.
3. IdP Trust - The IdP & SP trust mechanism is built in to ensure that only trusted Identity Provider can set an identity at service provider through the protocol.

The checks for MIM and other attacks are built in to each protocol and you can read the RFC/Specs for each of the protocol to see how they stop those attacks.

Answer (score 1):

The security of session tokens and session cookies is always an issue you must take into consideration – regardless of the fact if an SSO is used or not. Cookies and session tokens are stored in a browser and protected using various mechanisms.

- While they are stored in a browser, they can only be accessed by a
  specific website due to the Same-Origin Policy. So, if a cookie was
  set for the test.com, it would not be possible for the attacker.com
  to gain access to your cookie. However, you should always remember to
  use a trusted browser (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari) and keep it up
  to date.

- While the cookies are sent to a server and back, they are protected
  in transit using an encrypted connection (HTTPS). Even if an attacker
  is on the same Wi-Fi, they may capture the network traffic, but due
  to encryption, they will not be able to extract the cookies from it.

- If the application has any vulnerabilities (e.g., Cross-Site
  Scripting), it might be possible to impersonate the user, access
  their data, or perform actions from their account, however, this
  doesn't necessarily mean that the attacker will steal the cookies
  (and this is not always possible due to the *HttpOnly* flag) – the
  attacker might just perform actions directly from JavaScript.

So, stealing tokens is one thing. Another is being able to create a valid token for any user on your own – and this is a whole different story.

In web applications, we mostly have cookies and JSON Web Tokens (JWT).

- A **cookie** is a random string saved in a database and tied to a
  specific user. If the entropy of a cookie is not sufficient (or is
  generated predictably), an attacker might be able to generate a valid
  cookie and impersonate a user with a specific session. [You can find
  out more about cookies and session management in OWASP Cheat Sheets.](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html)
  If you are interested in the concept of randomness, [check out this
  article about the entropy of UUIDs.](https://neilmadden.blog/2018/08/30/moving-away-from-uuids/)
- A **JWT** is a stateless token signed cryptographically. It doesn’t need
  to be saved in a database – it contains all required information,
  like when it is valid, for whom, and what user it belongs to. You
  only need to verify the signature. The JWT can be signed using
  symmetric cryptography with a secret (HMAC) or asymmetric
  cryptography (RSA). The most obvious attack that would make it
  possible to impersonate a user is made by gaining access to a secret
  or private key and being able to create a valid token for any user.
  [You can read more about JWT attacks on PortSwigger Academy.](https://portswigger.net/web-security/jwt)

Considering all the above information, let's now move on to the SSO.

First, **Identity Providers not only provide tokens – they provide confirmation of the user's identity**, and providing a token is just a way of doing it. The Identity Provider and the Service Provider have a trusting relationship – which is established during the configuration process by providing proper certificates, secrets, and URLs.

In **SAML**, the flow may look as follows:

1. A user initiates the login flow at the Service Provider's website.
2. The Service Provider redirects the user to the Identity Provider
   with an AuthnRequest ("Hi Identity Provider, could you please
   authenticate this user for me?").
3. The Identity Provider authenticates the user, e.g., by asking the
   user for their login and password. If the provided credentials are
   correct, the Identity Provider does two things:

   a. Creates a session in the Identity Provider's application, so the next time the user tries to log in using this Identity Provider, they do not have to provide the credentials again (the session might expire or require reauthentication after a specific period, e.g., a week, but if a user tries to log in the next day, it will be transparent for them).

   b. Creates a signed XML document called *SAML Response*, which contains the requested information about the user's identity as well as some technical details (when the *SAML Response* was created, who signed it, how long it is valid, for whom it is valid). Then they send the *SAML Response* back to the Service Provider.
4. The Service Provider verifies the *SAML Response* by checking the
   signature against Identity Provider's certificate that the Service
   Provider has in their configuration. If the *SAML Response* is valid,
   the Service Provider can:

   a. Create a new session in their application (using a cookie or a token – however they want). This is the most common way – hence, the *SAML Responses* are usually valid for 3-5 minutes and are only possible to use once.

   b. Use the received *SAML Response* as a session token. However, it would require the *SAML Response* to be valid longer and allow multiple usage of the response. It is also not very practical, as *SAML Responses* are quite large compared to a cookie or JWT.

[You can read more about SAML and possible attacks on our blog.](https://www.securing.pl/en/saml-what-can-go-wrong-security-check/)

In **OpenID Connect**, the most popular flow looks as follows:

1. The user initiates the login flow at the Service Provider.
2. The Service Provider redirects the user to the Identity Provider.
3. The Identity Provider authenticates the user and creates a session
   in the Identity Provider's application. Then the Identity Provider
   redirects the user back to the Service Provider with a *code*.
4. The Service Provider receives the *code* and sends it to the Identity
   Provider via back channel (not via user’s browser). This connection
   is done by the application backend, it is encrypted and
   authenticated (the Service Provider must provide the *client_id* and
   *client_secret*). The Identity Provider checks the *code* and its
   validity, they create an *id_token* and send it back to the Service
   Provider. The *id_token* is a JWT – it is a JSON containing user data
   signed by the Identity Provider, which can be verified
   cryptographically by the Service Provider.
5. After receiving the *id_token*, the Service Provider can now do one of
   the following:

   a. Use the *id_token* as a session token.

   b. Create their own session based on the *id_token*. This solution is chosen much more often since the applications usually allow other authentication methods (login form, different OIDC providers, magic links etc.), and the applications would like to produce the same session type regardless of the login method.

It should be noted that if the attacker can steal the code in the OpenID Connect (e.g., [due to an open redirect](https://sec.okta.com/articles/2021/02/stealing-oauth-tokens-open-redirects) or [improper web message configuration](https://portswigger.net/research/detecting-web-message-misconfigurations-for-cross-domain-credential-theft)), they can use it to authenticate and impersonate the user, even though they never touched any of the session tokens. The [PKCE extension](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/pkce/) helps mitigate some kinds of attacks but is also not bulletproof.

The last question is how you can detect if a token is used in an unauthorized manner. Here are some tips:

- Remember about [logging & monitoring](https://owasp.org/Top10/A09_2021-Security_Logging_and_Monitoring_Failures/).
- Look out for extensive login attempts, especially failed ones.
- Verify if the token (*SAML Response*, OIDC *code*) has not been used
  before. Fail and log if it is expired or already been used.
- Always check if your application is the designated recipient of the
  token. If not – the token is probably misused.
- Allow the user to list and end all their sessions.